# Send CF7 unique message ID to Google Sheets (Flamingo _serial_number or CRM Entries Entity ID)

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, contact-form-7, wordpress-flamingo-plugin

I'm working with [CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and [CF7 Google Sheets Connector](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/integration-for-contact-form-7-and-google-sheets/).

I have a (very) simple warranty claims form and they need a ticket number. I have [Flamingo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/) installed, so I can send the unique incremental [_serial_number] via email.

Now, I want to send the `[_serial_number]` to the Google Sheet to save the ticket number, but this field is not available. Tried adding as custom value meta {_serial_number} and didn't work

I also use [CRM Entries](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-entries/) to log the form submits, and they have `Entity ID` that I can send to Google Sheet, but can't use in the email subject. I'm fine using this ID as ticket number as they are unique, I just need to be able to use it in the Mail tab of the CF7.